# Query of every contestant with more than 2 users from a certain city who voted

Tags: php, mysql, count, distinct

I am running MySQL and I have a website where users can vote for articles of their own and other users anonymously. I am using GD-rating 1.9 and he disables voting twice for an article based on both cookies and IP. However, I am having users who have dynamic IP's from their ISP remove the cookie and vote for themselves everyday.

I would like an SQL way (preferable but php is OK) of viewing a summary of every article where a person from the same city has voted more than 3 times for that article.

The log file is formatted like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_gdsr_votes_log` (
  `record_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vote_type` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'article',
  `multi_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `vote` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `object` text NOT NULL,
  `voted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_agent` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zipcode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`record_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=21263 ;
```

`id` refers to the article and `city` refers to the voter's city.

---

Just to clarify the `user_id` is only for logged in users, which is a small % of the voters.

I also know that this will not stop any type of proxy voting, but I counter that in my voting code to not even consider it if certain ports are opened on the machine voting (harsh technique, but effective).

I also know that it's possible that users from a large city may have many people who use the site and or people may have friends from the same city see the article and vote for them. I plan to use some more data later on by using the population of the city to use an educated guess if it seems like legit voting. What spawned this idea is I had someone who lived in a city in Portugal who had a city population of about 5000, and yet one person's article kept getting 10 votes everyday from that city.

Comment: Why not just create a unique index on user_id, vote and article id? If you can figure out how to get a unique id for the data, then you don't have to worry about enforcing it, SQL will do it for you. I understand that this is a log table we are looking at, but the theory should work for your actual tables.

Comment: Because user_id is 0 for anyone who isn't logged in. (98% of the voters)

Comment: Ah - so much for that idea... The problem then is the anonymous users. You have no way of identifying unique users who vote on a particular article other than by IP/cookie. What other unique data do you have?

Comment: The city and country is automatically found by a GeoIP API, and is based upon the IP. So I am effectively filtering people on the city associated to their IP

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(votes) as numvotes, city, country
FROM `wp_gdsr_votes_log`
GROUP BY user_id, city, country
HAVING numvotes > 2
```

This is untested...

Comment: there is no column `votes` but `SUM(votes)` would effectively be the query `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM wp_gdsr_votes_log where id=:id`  where `:id` whould be every id in `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM wp_gdsr_votes_log`